# What is this unusual structure inside this banana?

Tags: plant-anatomy

I was eating a banana, and I found this strange biological structure inside of it.

[image]

It was a bit tougher than the banana, and ran inside of the body through most of the length. To be clear, I peeled back banana with my fingers to reveal it; it was enveloped inside. It was accompanied by a small void.

No idea what this is, never seen anything like it. It didn't taste good. I'm thinking it might be a mutation. Anyone know what this is?

Comment: "*didn't taste good*"? Are you insane?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri thought it might give me powers.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I would assume that's how OP found out something was wrong with their banana. :-)

Comment: @John yep :√) 

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like some species of *Nigrospora* genus took over the inside of that banana. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigrospora_sphaerica), *[N. sphaerica](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30786385)* was first isolated from bananas. The other species that you will find referenced online is *[N. oryzae](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276284621_Griseofulvin_Producing_Endophytic_Nigrospora_oryzae_from_Indian_Emblica_officinalis_Gaertn_a_New_Report)*. In the articles I 
cite below the colonies are grown in potato dextrose, though.

Here is a picture of the red fungus inside a banana (from the [Canadian Food Inspection Agency](https://www.inspection.gc.ca/food-safety-for-industry/information-for-consumers/fact-sheets-and-infographics/products-and-risks/fruits-and-vegetables/red-fungus-inside-bananas/eng/1474985239822/1474985361544)):

[image: banana]

Googling '*Nigrosporia* banana' also returns lots of similar pictures.

To get a better answer, a sample could be taken from the banana and then cross-check what you see under the microscope with the *oryzae* morphology images seen in the researchgate article.

Comment: Well I won’t be eating bananas again.

Comment: That's freaky, I don't like that.

Comment: @Phoenix Just get revenge on their (distant) family, by consuming copious amounts of mushrooms.  It's just like the mafia... only eating food.

Comment: Wikipedia says it has antiviral properties. Maybe you should eat it?

Comment: @CJDennis It has some side-effects too, so I wouldn't recommend it. Although apparently they've successfully used it against MRSA cultures, so perhaps it has potential in derivative form. But I suspect this is one of those cases where the cure is worse than the original ailment.